# Working with a Shared Resource Pool and project plan revisions

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, resources

We have a practice of saving a copy of our project plan with the status date in the filename every time we update status. This messes up the shared resource pool, because the resource pool now thinks that the updated file is ANOTHER project.

The workaround is to open the older version, remove the shared resource, and edit the resource pool and break the link to the older version(s). But this seems tedious and overly manual.

Is there a technique on the resource pool / save a copy side that can deactivate the older versions of the project, or tag two versions of the project as actually being the same project?

Or is our approach of saving backups of our project plans the incorrect workflow, and if so, what do you recommend as a safeguard against project corruption or user entry error?

Answer (score 1):

There is no other work around nor technique for re-naming or saving a connected file.  The ultimate answer is Project Server either on premises on hosted through Project Online.

I would also be scrupulous about backing up the pool file.

Comment: Thanks Julie for the response. In the case of backing up the Project files, is the approach I describe (unlinking / removing the shared resource pool from the older version of the Project file) the best way to ensure I don't "double dip" my resources?

Comment: My suggestion is to ensure that the project resource pool file and all active sharer files are stored in the same network directly.  Back up all files in the directory regularly.